# hibernate foreign key is updating all fields in ref table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am new to this forum and hibernate. I am having a problem with hibernate many-to-one mapping.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "DTE_ID")
@NotNull
private Dte raisedByDte;
```

This is the code I am using in main object and foreign key is `DTE_ID`. But when I am trying to save it is updating all fields in referenced table. My reference object is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DTE_MASTERS",  uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "DTE_NAME"))
public class Dte {

   @Id  
   @Column(name="DTE_ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
   private int dte_id;
   @Column(name="DTE_NAME")
   private String dte_name;

   public Dte() {
      super();
      // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }
   public Dte(int dte_id, String dte_name) {
      super();
      this.dte_id = dte_id;
      this.dte_name = dte_name;
   }
   public int getDte_id() {
      return dte_id;
   }
   public void setDte_id(int dte_id) {
      this.dte_id = dte_id;
   }
   public String getDte_name() {
      return dte_name;
   }
   public void setDte_name(String dte_name) {
      this.dte_name = dte_name;
   }
```

I want to restrict the update of `DTE_MASTERS` when I am inserting ..can some body please guide me through this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the cascade option from the mapping. It enforces the same operation as was performed on the parent object. 
I am guessing that you are doing `merge()` on the main object.. and with that option, the `merge()` (which would result in an update if the entity is not new) will also be invoked on the `Dte` dependency:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Also, keep in mind that if you any non-transient field within the `Dte` entity once its loaded with the main entity, all of the changes will be commited implicilty upon the transaction end.

In order to prevent that you would need to perform `session.evict(dte);` so that any changes will not get persisted in the database even if they were performed in within the transactional method.

Comment: Thanks for quick help can you explain                                                                             this , keep in mind that if you any non-transient field within the Dte entity once its loaded with the main entity, all of the changes will be commited implicilty upon the transaction end.

In order to prevent that you would need to perform session.detach(dte); so that any changes will not get persisted in the database even if they were performed in within the transactional method.

Comment: so.. once you retrieve the entity within a transaction it is within the persistence context till the end of transaction (unless you call evict). Now any change you make to that object state.. will be flushed to the database.. regardless if you used update / saveOrUpdate

Comment: Sure @Maciej Kowalski .Thank you for quick response and guidance